# Average of Rows in 2D List/Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I need a little help with a question on an assignment, I'm not even too sure how to begin other than creating the 2D list, the question is as follows

"Write a Python function that accepts the 2D table using a list of lists that will print the average review for each reviewer. Your program must work on any 2D array that is used."

[Example of reviewer / movie review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxG6u.png)

I have this part done which creates the 2d array for the above attached pictures, where should I go from here?

```
array = [ [4,6,2,5], [7,9,4,8], [6,9,3,7] ]

def review(array):
    for row in array:
        for entry in row:
            print(entry, end='  ')
        print()
```

Which creates:

```
review(array)
4  6  2  5  
7  9  4  8  
6  9  3  7
```

How would I go about finding out the average of the rows in the 2d array?

Edit: Example of output for the above table:

```
review([ enter table ])
Reviewer 0 average rating: 4.25
Reviewer 1 average rating: 7
Reviewer 2 average rating: 6.25
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: added the start to my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great to have a real example of the data, but assuming its something like : [[2,3,4],[2,3],[1,4,5,6]], the following should work. It computes the mean in each nested list and outputs it in the same order.

```
def mean_score(table):
    for i, reviewer in enumerate(table):
        score = float(sum(reviewer))/len(reviewer)    
        print 'Reviewer %i average rating: %.2f' %(i,score)
return
```

Comment: added some sample data and what I have so far, I'd use numpy but we've yet to cover it in class and my professor won't accept it.

Comment: well then `[float(sum(reviewer))/len(reviewer) for reviewer in table]`

Comment: added example output

Comment: did an edit, that should work

Comment: with that code I get,

review(table)
Reviewer 0 average rating: 4.250000
1

Comment: i added, and so should you .2 in front of %f so it will be %.2f. Also if you are interested in coding, try to make it a habit to use the documentation :). It will be hard at first but very valuable later on; Also I deleted the return 1 so you wont get the 1.

Comment: You're welcome, you could accept my answer then to close this question. It will be an awesome experience, you can create in your bedroom using a computer with coding. :)